# discord.js - awaiting messages and checking for dm messages

Tags: discord.js

nothing i do is working i been looking all throughout the internet and nothing would help me
please help my code is below.
i am using discord.js with node.js 14.15.0,
this code isnt inside the main.js file so client. wont work,
im using a collection for the commands

im trying to check when the user responds to a message in their dm

```
if(message.channel.type === 'dm'){
    message.channel.awaitMessages(message.author.id, {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
         console.log(message.author);
         if(collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'cancel'){
              message.author.send('canceled');
         }
    }).catch(err =>{
         message.author.send('took too long canceling');
    });
 };
```

Comment: "Won't work" is not enough to diagnose an issue. What's going wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst awaiting messages in a DM channel `message.author.send` is not valid.
As these DMs are still in a channel `message.channel.send` will work just fine.
Example Code:

```js
client.on('message', message => { //Adding the event listener
    if(message.channel.type === 'dm') { //If the message was via direct message
        message.channel.awaitMessages(message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => { //awaiting the next message
            if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') { //if the awaited message is equal to 'cancel'
                message.channel.send('Canceled prompt.'); //let the user know that their erequest has been canceled
            }
        }).catch {
            message.channel.send('Timeout proceeded, canceling.'); //if the user has ran out of time, let them know
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: i cant use client.on because i did it in main.js and how im calling the commands is through a collection in another folder using module.exports. what im doing to make this script run is in the discord when a player saids the command, it will send them a dm outside the server with an embed, then im trying to wait for them to respond in that dm but it isnt working. any thoughts on this better explanation

Comment: You will need to pass the client object through your code somewhere. My suggestion is that you pass client through all of your files when you export them.

Comment: i dont know what you mean. my client.on: wont format right:

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'embed'){
        client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'info'){
        client.commands.get('info').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'xera'){
        client.commands.get('xera').execute(message, args);
    }
});

Comment: Where you put `.execute(message, args)` change it to `.execute(message, args, client)`.

Comment: when i put in a number this error shows any thoughts on this?

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [my user id], which is a string and not a function

Comment: wait no its this error: (node:22640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.